# Разбить текст от точки до точки.

Tags: php

Есть .txt файл. Не форматированный " как есть " скачанный из сети. Скажем это книга. 
Нужно: Разбить данный файл на предложения ( от точки до точки ), НО что бы предложения включая символы были не длиннее 140 символов.

> Например это предложение замечательно
> вместится в сто сорок символов и
> подойдет к этой небольшой, но
> интересной задачке, как-то так раз
> два.

Предложения которые превышают 140 символов ( учитывая точку в конце ) - скрипт отбрасывает.
Принтит на вывод построчно вида:
предложение
предложение
предложение
предложение

Я знаю, что есть функция substr . ей надо 3 аргумента. Первый-сама строка,второй-с какого символа начать обрезать текст(нумерация начинается с нуля), и третий-сколько символов обрезать.
Но может как-то еще реально это сделать? т.к. substr у меня не получилось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sentences = explode('.', $text);
$sentences = array_filter($sentences, function($s) {
    $s = trim($s);
    return strlen($s) > 0 && strlen($s) < 140;
});
```

p.s. на больших данных наверняка умрет
p.p.s. откуда у меня ощущение, что у этого задания есть какой-то конкретный заказчик?

Comment: Нет, никакого заказчика нет)) это для личного пользования ( твиттеры ). Спасибо за Ваше решение! Сейчас еще на Yii накуралесил слегка. СПАСИБО!